# How can we capture a pull request which is created in bitbucket cloud

Tags: git, jenkins, scripting, bitbucket, pull-request

I'm writing a shell script which should be trigger once there a Pull request is created in Bitbucket. My question is what are the ways to capture the Pull request. I found two ways as of now.

1) Create a hook plugin in bitbucket which captures the pull request.

2) Create a jenkins job and with relevant plugin in jenkins which captures pull request and can trigger my shell script in build actions.

Is there any other way to capture the Pull request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to capture the Pull request?

Not really: you have listed the two common approaches:

- push (webhook pushing an event to a listener)
- pull (querying the BitBucket API)

In the latter case, you would use he [PR Rest resource API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.8.0/bitbucket-rest.html#idm46057171662880):

```
/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests
```